# Possible to run jekyll serve --livereload on two different directories with two different ports at the same time?

Tags: jekyll

I'm using `jekyll serve --livereload` on port 4000 (the default). It works. However, when I try to run the same command but on a different port with something like `jekyll serve --livereload -P 4001`, I get and error:

```
eventmachone.rb:351: 'start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
```

Is there anyway to run --livereload on two different sites at the same time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set 2 different ports. One for Jekyll and second for LiveReload.

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload --livereload-port 8080 --port 4001
```

You will see the options that interest you by calling the command `jekyll help serve`:

```
-P, --port [PORT]  Port to listen on
--livereload-port [PORT]  Port for LiveReload to listen on
```